# XenServer 6.0 Advanced - Is it an add-on or part of initial install?

Tags: installation, xenserver

I'm looking to purchase a new dedicated server and have XenServer 6.0 installed. There is an option to include XenServer 6.0 Advanced which has some additional features. However we don't need those additional features for a few months.

Is "Advanced" something you can add-on without a complete re-install of XenServer or must it be part of the original installation of XenServer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Editions have to do with licenses only and the licenses can be applied and changed late without reinstall, if you initially only installed the free license.

Comment: this was confirmed by my SoftLayer sales guy as well.